# Excel calculation - number of digits when copied

Tags: indexing, match, digits, significant-digits

So, this might be a very specific use-case, I'm not sure. I'm a Scientist who works with HPLC data. The data is handled in a piece of software called Chromeleon, where reports are built in an Excel-style spreadsheet. While it looks suspiciously like Excel, there are certain things that don't work. Because of this, some things might not be the exact same, but I think we'll have to assume that it is the same, for the sake of this question.

I have a field in my Overview-sheet that contains an Index-Match function, which fetches a value from another sheet (Summary). In the Summary-sheet, the value is displayed with 2 digits (eg. 32.41), but it actually contains many more (e.g. 32.411255252). When the Index-Match function fetches the value, I can choose how many digits it should fetch, so if I were to choose 0.000 in Cell Formatting, it would print 32.411.

However. On the Overview-sheet, I want it to contain ALL the digits from the Summary-sheet, but only display 1. So I want it to print 32.4 in the cell, but when you copy the value and paste it into another workbook, I want it to include all the digits.

Additional info: When I choose Cell Formatting in the Overview sheet (which contains the Index-Match cell), the categories are more limited than in Excel. It is automatically set to "FIXED". I can choose "Custom" and type in something instead, but apart from that nothing seems relevant. There is no Number-category as there usually is in Excel.

I hope my explanation and question makes sense - and that someone has experience with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Damn. Sure is quiet here. Impossible question?

Comment: Can you include screenshots of the Cell Formatting screens? Are you limited to predefined values, can you type in custom formatting masks, et cetera?  Most people here don't have $12,000 to spend on a copy of Chromeleon to try and work out what the differences are between Chromeleon and Excel or Google Sheets...  I *suspect* that a customer Number Format of `#0` would probably be possible somehow.  (And, does Chromeleon have its own support forum, where you might find experts in the program?)

Comment: I've asked Thermo, makers of Chromeleon, but no luck so far. Here are my options for Format Cells. It seems to be possible to add custom formatting under "All", but there's no 'Custom' as in Excel.

https://ibb.co/fM7cMkS